# How to use a completion handler inside the completion handler

Tags: swift

I have type aliased the completion handler as below, having a completion handler inside the completion handler.

```
typealias voidCompletionHandler = () -> Void
typealias dataCompletionHandler = (Data, [String: String], voidCompletionHandler) -> Void
```

I wanted to use computed properties to define the completion handler.

```
var completion: dataCompletionHandler {
    return { data, _, completion in
        jsonDataProcess(data: data) { json in // ERROR --> This is SwiftyJSON process with completion handler.
            if json != nil {
            Country.instantiate(json: json!) {. // ERROR --> The is Core Data process with completion handler
                completion()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code, I get "Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'completion'.

The sub processes also has @escaping so, they are not the problem. It is the completion handler inside the dataCompletionHandler that I do not know how to define it as @escaping.

```
// Inside JSON Handler class
func jsonDataProcess(data: Data, completion: @escaping jsonCompletionHandler) {
    do {
        let json = try JSON(data: data)
        if json["Status"].string == "Success" {
            completion(json["Data"])
        } else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
        completion(nil)
    }
}

// Inside Country Class
static func instantiate(json: JSON, completion: @escaping voidCompletionHandler) {
    container.performBackgroundTask { (context) in
        let country = Country(context: context)
        country.name = json["name"].string
        country.iso2digit = json["alpha-2"].string
        country.iso3digit = json["alpha-3"].string
        country.region = json["region"].string
        try? context.save()
        print("Country.instantiate : \(String(describing: json["alpha-2"].string))")
        completion()
    }
}
```

How do I make the completion handler inside the completion handler as @escaping when using as computed property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the escaping declaration  part of the typealias.